# The content of an array is suspiciously doubled

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have been building an app that simulates the way a printer works. While designing the app, I have created the method below that splits a String content depending on the number of pages required. All the function seems to process the data correctly but I don't know why the method keeps doubling the content of an array it's supposed to return. Here's the method.

```
public ArrayList<String> splitContentIntoPages(){
    int startPosition = 0;
    int endIndexCalc = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<getPages(); i++){
        if((getContent().length() - endIndexCalc) >= getSize().getCapacity()){  
            System.out.println("Start " + startPosition);
            endIndexCalc = startPosition + (getSize().getCapacity());
            this.pagesContent.add(getContent().substring(startPosition, endIndexCalc));
            startPosition += getSize().getCapacity();
            System.out.println("End  " + endIndexCalc);
        }else{
            this.pagesContent.add(getContent().substring(startPosition));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Size of the array " + this.pagesContent.size() + "  getPages() " + getPages() + "");
    for(int i=0; i<this.pagesContent.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("The content :" + this.pagesContent.get(i));
    }
    return this.pagesContent;
}
```

I need some fresher eye on the issue. I have spent too much time on that trying to understand what's wrong. Thanks a lot guys!

Here's the version without debugs

```
public ArrayList<String> splitContentIntoPages(){
    int startPosition = 0;
    int endIndexCalc = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<getPages(); i++){
        if((getContent().length() - endIndexCalc) >= getSize().getCapacity()){  
            endIndexCalc = startPosition + (getSize().getCapacity());
            this.pagesContent.add(getContent().substring(startPosition, endIndexCalc));
            startPosition += getSize().getCapacity();
        }else{
            this.pagesContent.add(getContent().substring(startPosition));
        }
    }
    return this.pagesContent;
}
```

[this is the test entry extraxt. Basically the method aboe is processing the string of chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yob6o.jpg)

[that's the outcome. Basically, the string is supposed to be split into the number of pages - in this case 2. However, the array that is holding the split element of the strings holds 4 pieces of strings instead of two. It's all doubled. And I have no idea why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SJFA.jpg)

Comment: What does "suspiciously doubled" mean? Please show the input (as well as values returned by methods called here), expected and actual outputs.

Comment: @Andy Turner - I have updated the request. Have a look :) thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I think it is highly possible that you use a global variable to store the content. And every time you call the method you split and insert content into the global variable, but never clear it. This make your global content increased every time you call it again. I suggest you to rewrite the method that takes in a string and return a list of string instead of using a global variable.

Comment: @Surely well I have just tried to put the content as an attribute of the method but the outcome's still the same... Unless I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either clear `this.pagesContent` at the beginning of `splitContentIntoPages()` or create new `ArrayList<String> newA = new ArrayList<String>()` at the beginning, add everythig to this new arrayList and at the end of  `splitContentIntoPages()` do `this.pagesContent = newA`

Comment: this's worked! Thanks but would you explain me it works that way? :) Is it something about the types of variables or some sort of internal confusion?

Comment: @bwielk My guess is that you have created one object of the class containing method splitContentIntoPages that you are using multiple times. As this.pagesContent is a variable declared inside the object (and not in the method)it retains it's value after execution of splitContentIntoPages.In each new excution of splitContentIntoPages you add new strings to pagesContent and never clear it. For example: in first execution this.pagesContent is empty and you add "a" - the "a" is remembered. Execute it second time - you again add "a" and now this.pagesContent contains "a","a". Third time-"a","a","a"